# Enable binary SI units with siunitx in MacTeX

Tags: errors, siunitx

I'm using TeXShop on OS X Lion (the MacTeX distro, which is kind of amazing) and I cannot do the following with `siunitx`:

```
\SI{4}{\giga\byte}
```

TeXShop says it's an "Undefined control sequence."  According to the manual I should be able to do this:

```
\usepackage[detect-weight=true, binary-units=true]{siunitx}
```

or this:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ detect-weight=true, binary-units=true }
```

but that's not working, and I've tried small variants.

How can I make the "byte" unit work?

Comment: I was able to solve this by doing the following:

`\usepackage[detect-weight=true, load-configurations=binary]{siunitx}`

I did that instead of my existing siunitx usepackage statement.

I don't know if this will be useful to anybody else, it required a little digging on my part, so maybe someone else won't have to do that digging now.

Sorry to put this as a comment - I don't have enough rep to post an answer to my own question so soon.

Comment: What version of [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) do you have? To find out, add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and view the `.log` file.

Comment: I tried what you had in your question (not in your comment) and everything worked fine. Whatever the problem, I don't think it is texshop's doing.

Comment: This looks like the classic 'Not checking the documentation for the package version you have installed' issue. Picking up option names from an internet search without checking on what you have installed is always a risk. I'd suggest this is 'too localized'.

Comment: @JosephWright but maybe someone else tries the same, fails and finds this page here... so maybe you could make your comment an answer, stating that he used invalid options or a wrong version, link to the [siunitx documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and/or post an example of how it would be done correctly. Would help the person, and you can be shure to get at least my upvote

Comment: Aha!  I didn't know how to check versions...  I have version 2.2 on here, after which "load-configurations has been deprecated" according to the manual.  I read the section of the manual for what I wanted to do, but didn't read the section regarding my version, as you suggested @JosephWright.  I didn't download this all that long ago, and I didn't figure the options had changed in that time...  Oops!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue has occurred as you've tried to use an option from a newer version of `siunitx` than you have installed. Always check the documentation for the version of `siunitx` you have installed, easiest to do using

```
texdoc siunitx
```

at the Command Prompt/Terminal.

(This is a general point: it's true of any package.)

Comment: So, you wrote `siunitx`?  It's very handy.  Thanks.